# Sub query filter in LEFT/RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I tried following query to get the missing records in TAB1

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1 T1 
RIGHT JOIN TAB2 T2 ON T1.MemNo = T2.MemID
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM TAB3 x 
               WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID
               AND x.Col1 = T1.SID )
AND T1.MemNo IS NULL
```

But it doesn't give any results

Sample data;

```
TAB1

MemNo   SID

116537  S110
116537  D011
575777  D012
214438  S110
434611  D114
214438  D011
208368  D012
208368  S110

TAB2

MemID   SVID

116537  110
116537  11
214438  11
434675  114
214438  110
575788  12
208368  12
208368  110


TAB3

Col1    Col2

D011    11
S110    110
D114    114
D012    12
```

How should I change the query to get the expected results. Which is mentioned as below

```
TAB2

MemID   SVID

575788  12
434675  114
```

In case of INNER JOIN this works fine

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query, written so I understand it better:

```
select *
from tab2 t2 left outer join
     tab1 t1
     on t1.MemNo = t2.MemId
where exists (SELECT 1
              FROM TAB3 x 
              WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID AND x.Col1 = T1.SID ) and
      T1.MemNo IS NULL
```

The column `t1.MemNo` is NULL only when the outer join fails to find a match in that table (because it is part of the join condition).  When this is `NULL` then so is `T1.SID`, so the `exists` clause will find no rows because one of the `AND` conditions evaluates to `NULL`.

If you want to handle this case, then you need logic in the `exists` clause as well:

```
select *
from tab2 t2 left outer join
     tab1 t1
     on t1.MemNo = t2.MemId
where exists (SELECT 1
              FROM TAB3 x 
              WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID AND (x.Col1 = T1.SID or t1.SID is null)) and
      T1.MemNo IS NULL;
```

Comment: Excellent Gordon. Good stuff